# Icon in Qt::DecorationRole - causes a crash

Tags: c++, qt, tableview, tablemodel, qicon

I'm writing an application with TableView, custom model (QAbstractTableModel descendant) and icons in cells. Firstly i've tried to make an icons cache, but fall into Access Violation (at address 0x0) while expanding main window with table to fullscreen.

Qt version is 5.5.1

Windows 8.1

On another two machines problem is **not** reproducable.
The same .exe file can cause an AV on a target machine and run ok on another two.

What am I doing wrong? How to debug to the source of a problem?

Then i've tried to reproduce the problem and made a simplest application:

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QFileIconProvider>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class SimpleTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    QFileIconProvider iconProvider;

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    SimpleTableModel model;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "filetypeiconprovider.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->tableView->setModel(&model);
}

int SimpleTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 100;
}

int SimpleTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 5;
}

QVariant SimpleTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();


    switch(role){
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
            return QString("qwe");
            break;

        case Qt::BackgroundRole:
            if (index.row() % 2)
                return QBrush(QColor(0xfcf2fb));
            else
                return QBrush(0xfcfcf2);

            break;

        case Qt::DecorationRole:
            //if (index.column() == 0)
                {
                    QIcon icon;
                    QFileInfo fileInfo("e:\\ss_source\\youcam-tutorial.exe");
                    icon = iconProvider.icon(fileInfo);

                    return icon;

                }
            break;

        }

    return QVariant();
}
```

And This code results in Access Violation while triying to expand the program window to fullscreen:

```
c:\work\build\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtbase\src\gui\painting\qtransform.cpp:2047: ошибка: Exception at 0x5dd991fc, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)
```

The stack trace is:

```
1   QTransform::type    qtransform.cpp  2047    0x5dd991fc  
2   QRasterPaintEngine::drawImage   qpaintengine_raster.cpp 2202    0x5dd1206b  
3   QRasterPaintEngine::drawPixmap  qpaintengine_raster.cpp 2052    0x5dd119bb  
4   QPainter::drawPixmap    qpainter.cpp    5196    0x5dd2dfe2  
5   QPainter::drawPixmap    qpainter.h  774 0x5da1ee2d  
6   QPixmapIconEngine::paint    qicon.cpp   178 0x5db21bfd  
7   QIcon::paint    qicon.cpp   902 0x5db20a7c  
8   QCommonStyle::drawControl   qcommonstyle.cpp    2186    0x5e46555b  
9   QWindowsStyle::drawControl  qwindowsstyle.cpp   1864    0x5e4f1648  
10  QWindowsXPStyle::drawControl    qwindowsxpstyle.cpp 2533    0x5e4da053  
11  QWindowsVistaStyle::drawControl qwindowsvistastyle.cpp  1470    0x5e4cb7e6  
12  QStyledItemDelegate::paint  qstyleditemdelegate.cpp 414 0x5e79028e  
13  QTableViewPrivate::drawCell qtableview.cpp  923 0x5e7224ec  
14  QTableView::paintEvent  qtableview.cpp  1480    0x5e71c983  
15  QWidget::event  qwidget.cpp 8831    0x5e41004c  
16  QFrame::event   qframe.cpp  540 0x5e5767e2  
17  QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent  qabstractscrollarea.cpp 1200    0x5e617ef3  
18  QAbstractItemView::viewportEvent    qabstractitemview.cpp   1686    0x5e6e73f2  
19  QAbstractScrollAreaPrivate::viewportEvent   qabstractscrollarea_p.h 102 0x5e3bc678  
20  QAbstractScrollAreaFilter::eventFilter  qabstractscrollarea_p.h 118 0x5e61b9d9  
21  QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters  qcoreapplication.cpp    1072    0x642d8b03  
22  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    3712    0x5e3c53f2  
23  QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3681    0x5e3c3575  
24  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    965 0x642d8247  
25  QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent  qcoreapplication.h  227 0x643f7b08  
26  QWidgetPrivate::sendPaintEvent  qwidget.cpp 5625    0x5e41713f  
27  QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget  qwidget.cpp 5569    0x5e416dea  
28  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5761    0x5e4174ca  
29  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5748    0x5e4173f5  
30  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5748    0x5e4173f5  
31  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5748    0x5e4173f5  
32  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5748    0x5e4173f5  
33  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5748    0x5e4173f5  
34  QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget  qwidget.cpp 5619    0x5e4170e7  
35  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5761    0x5e4174ca  
36  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5748    0x5e4173f5  
37  QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget  qwidget.cpp 5619    0x5e4170e7  
38  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5761    0x5e4174ca  
39  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5748    0x5e4173f5  
40  QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive  qwidget.cpp 5748    0x5e4173f5  
41  QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget  qwidget.cpp 5619    0x5e4170e7  
42  QWidgetBackingStore::doSync qwidgetbackingstore.cpp 1229    0x5e3d8359  
43  QWidgetBackingStore::sync   qwidgetbackingstore.cpp 1033    0x5e3d6500  
44  QWidgetPrivate::syncBackingStore    qwidget.cpp 1904    0x5e418e01  
45  QWidgetWindow::handleResizeEvent    qwidgetwindow.cpp   705 0x5e444686  
46  QWidgetWindow::event    qwidgetwindow.cpp   233 0x5e4434a4  
47  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    3716    0x5e3c540e  
48  QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3160    0x5e3c182e  
49  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    965 0x642d8247  
50  QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent  qcoreapplication.h  227 0x643f7b08  
51  QGuiApplicationPrivate::processGeometryChangeEvent  qguiapplication.cpp 2067    0x5da648f7  
52  QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent    qguiapplication.cpp 1593    0x5da64fbd  
53  QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents  qwindowsysteminterface.cpp  625 0x5da399d1  
54  QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::sendPostedEvents    qwindowsguieventdispatcher.cpp  84  0x63cc4d4d  
55  qt_internal_proc    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    416 0x64368a1b  
56  _InternalCallWinProc    USER32      0x76458e71  
57  UserCallWinProcCheckWow USER32      0x764590d1  
58  DispatchMessageWorker   USER32      0x7645a66f  
59  DispatchMessageW    USER32      0x7645a6e0  
60  QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    818 0x6436946d  
61  QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents   qwindowsguieventdispatcher.cpp  74  0x63cc4c65  
62  QEventLoop::processEvents   qeventloop.cpp  129 0x642d3fac  
63  QEventLoop::exec    qeventloop.cpp  204 0x642d41b2  
64  QCoreApplication::exec  qcoreapplication.cpp    1229    0x642d6872  
65  QGuiApplication::exec   qguiapplication.cpp 1528    0x5da61848  
66  QApplication::exec  qapplication.cpp    2977    0x5e3c1489  
67  main    main.cpp    10  0x138435f   
68  WinMain qtmain_win.cpp  113 0x13a30ed   
69  __tmainCRTStartup   crtexe.c    618 0x13a24cf   
70  WinMainCRTStartup   crtexe.c    466 0x13a228d   
71  BaseThreadInitThunk KERNEL32        0x74c97c04  
72  __RtlUserThreadStart    ntdll       0x773ead1f  
73  _RtlUserThreadStart ntdll       0x773eacea
```

Comment: Are you sure, that `iconProvider.icon(fileInfo);` returns valid icon?

Comment: I've added `icon.isNull()` check, but nothing changed. The icon is valid because in this example you could see it - Until window is unwinded to fullscreen.

Comment: Are there other problems with fullscreen applications on this machine? If problem is not reproducible on other PC, then it's not a problem of your code/qt.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov No problems until this. I've been developing this app on this machine for a year, nothing suspicious happened. I would try to test not only app on other machines, but app with qt dlls from this machine.
All of this is rather strange, I'll be glad if someone pointer out how to debug this. Maybe there is a way to link with qt source and and debug it indepth?

Comment: First - be sure that your application uses same version of Qt on all computers. You need to do this check in runtime, to be sure that correct one is loaded.

Comment: Second - you have a Qt source, so you may use debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared on a target machine when compiling in newer Qt versions, like 5.6 and 5.7 in both bedug or release and using the same 32 or 64 bit MS VS 2013 compiler.